# Serialization/Deserialization. trying to write and read from a file

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

i'm trying to read and write to a file.
for the first part, writing list of objects to a binary file, i succeed to do so using serialization.

the problem was when i tried to read the back from the file to a list of objects, using deserialize. every time that i'm running the solution i get a runtime error.

the code:

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using MileStone1Fin.LogicLayer;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MileStone1Fin.PersistentLayer
{
    public class UserHandler
    {

        public UserHandler()
        {
        }

        public void addNewUser(List<User> users)
        {
            Stream myFileStream = File.Create("UsersData.bin");

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

            bf.Serialize(myFileStream, users);

            Console.WriteLine("5535");
            myFileStream.Close();


            List<User> newUsers1 = null;

            if (File.Exists("UsersData.bin"))
            {
                Stream myFileStream1 = File.OpenRead("UsersData.bin");

                BinaryFormatter bf1 = new BinaryFormatter();

                newUsers1 = (List<User>)bf1.Deserialize(myFileStream1);//this line marked as the problem one according to visual studio

                myFileStream1.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Line 38 is the problematic line
The code that made the call:

```
public void registration(String nickname, String groupID)
    {
        if(checkUserValidity(nickname, groupID))
        {
            User newUser = new User(nickname, groupID);
            users.Add(newUser);
            userHandler.addNewUser(users);




User class:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationExeption - the runtime error


    using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using MileStoneClient.CommunicationLayer;
using MileStone1Fin.PersistentLayer;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace MileStone1Fin.LogicLayer
{
    ///<summary>
    /// This class taking care for the functionallity of the user objects.
    /// The user class will be part of the Logic layer
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable()]
    public class User : ISerializable
    {
        private static UserHandler userHandler = new UserHandler();
        private String nickname { get; set; }
        private String groupID { get; set; }
        private bool status { get; set; }
        DateTime lastSeen { get; set; }

        public User(String nickname, String groupID) //The User class constructor
        {
            this.nickname = nickname;
            this.groupID = groupID;
            this.lastSeen = DateTime.Now;
            this.status = false;

        }

        /*public Message send(String msg) //Creates a Imessage object, return a Message object contains GUID, time, user
        {                               //information, message body
            IMessage message = Communication.Instance.Send(ChatRoom.url, this.groupID, this.nickname, msg);//sends the neccesary details to the server
            return new Message(message);
        }*/

        public void logout()
        {
            this.status = false;
            //Console.WriteLine(this.nickname + "You were disconnected from the server");
            lastSeen = DateTime.Now;
            //Console.WriteLine(lastSeen);
            //need to write into file
        }

        private bool isOnline()
        {
            return this.status;
        }

        public void lastSeenDate()
        {
            if (isOnline())
                Console.WriteLine("Online now");
            else
                Console.WriteLine(lastSeen.ToString());
        }

        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue("Nickname", nickname);
            info.AddValue("GroupId", groupID);
            info.AddValue("LastSeen", lastSeen);
            info.AddValue("Status", status);
        }

        public User(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            nickname = (string)info.GetValue("Name", typeof(string));
            groupID = (string)info.GetValue("GroupId", typeof(string));
            lastSeen = (DateTime)info.GetValue("LastSeen", typeof(DateTime));
            status = (Boolean)info.GetValue("Status", typeof(Boolean));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What runtime error do you get? And on what line? Please show your `User` class as well.

Comment: i've just edited the question

Comment: @Sprint21 The error must have included a stack trace. Can you include that?

Comment: There is more to the error than that, it should say some kind of description or message along with it.

Comment: `nickname = (string)info.GetValue("Name", typeof(string));` Might be your problem, you are serializing "Nickname" but trying to read "Name".

Comment: @RonBeyer You are a great man! :) ty, it fixed my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is how you are naming things with serialization, you are serializing `Nickname` and trying to read it out as `Name`. The safest thing to do is to get the name right from the property:

```
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue(nameof(nickname), nickname);
        info.AddValue(nameof(groupID), groupID);
        info.AddValue(nameof(lastSeen), lastSeen);
        info.AddValue(nameof(status), status);
    }

    public User(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        nickname = (string)info.GetValue(nameof(nickname), typeof(string));
        groupID = (string)info.GetValue(nameof(groupID), typeof(string));
        lastSeen = (DateTime)info.GetValue(nameof(lastSeen), typeof(DateTime));
        status = (Boolean)info.GetValue(nameof(status), typeof(Boolean));
    }
}
```

Which has the added benefit of when you rename your properties (to the .NET standard), it will automatically rename your code as well. This can cause issues if you rename something and then try to load an old file, so be careful, but at least this way you don't have magic strings floating around in your code. You can avoid the above problem by writing version information to the serialization stream and deserializing based on a version.